# Creating an irregular list of lists from a single list

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to create a list of lists from a single list. I'm able to do this if the new list of lists have the same number of elements, however this will not always be the case

As said earlier, the function below works when the list of lists have the same number of elements.

I've tried using regular expressions to determine if an element matches a pattern using
`pattern2=re.compile(r'\d\d\d\d\d\d')` because the first value on my new list of lists will always be 6 digits and it will be the only one that follows that format. However, i'm not sure of the syntax of getting it to stop at the next match and create another list

```
def chunks(l,n):
    for i in range(0,len(l),n):
        yield l[i:i+n]
```

The code above works if the list of lists will contain the same number of elements

Below is what I expect.

```
OldList=[111111,a,b,c,d,222222,a,b,c,333333,a,d,e,f]
DesiredList=[[111111,a,b,c,d],[222222,a,b,c],[333333,a,d,e,f]]
```

Many thanks indeed.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely a much more efficient way to do this (with fewer loops), but here is one approach that finds the indexes of the breakpoints and then slices the list from index to index appending `None` to the end of the indexes list to capture the remaining items. If your 6 digit numbers are really strings, then you could eliminate the `str()` inside `re.match()`.

```
import re

d = [111111,'a','b','c','d',222222,'a','b','c',333333,'a','d','e','f']      

indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(d) if re.match(r'\d{6}', str(x))]
groups = [d[s:e] for s, e in zip(indexes, indexes[1:] + [None])]
print(groups)
# [[111111, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [222222, 'a', 'b', 'c'], [333333, 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fold.

First, define a function to locate the start flag:

```
>>> def is_start_flag(v):
...     return len(v) == 6 and v.isdigit()
```

That will be useful if the flags are not exactly what you expected them to be, or to exclude some false positives, or even if you need a regex.

Then use `functools.reduce`:

```
>>> L = d = ['111111', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '222222', 'a', 'b', 'c', '333333', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> import functools
>>> functools.reduce(lambda acc, x: acc+[[x]] if is_start_flag(x) else acc[:-1]+[acc[-1]+[x]], L, [])
[['111111', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['222222', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['333333', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
```

If the next element `x` is the start flag, then append a new list `[x]` to the accumulator. Else, add the element to the current list, ie the last list of the accumulator.